# Spring Batch aggregate operation on collected data after step

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Job that reads from a csv file and writes each (transformed) line out to a database.  It operates on chunks of lines.  I need to add a feature such that while the lines are being processed, I store a selection of line ID's.  After all the lines have been processed and written, I need to go back and modify those selected lines.

I was considering using afterJob with JobExecutionListener to execute this operation after the step is complete, however I do not know the best way to store the data as each chunk is processed, and then access it from the listener at the end.  The data would be a Map with thousands of entries.  It seems to me that putting this whole Map into ExecutionContext is not the right solution, as it seems to be intended to store simple flags, parameters, etc.

Below is the config and I can add other code snippets if that's helpful.

```java
// JobLauncher config
protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(asyncExecutor);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

// Job config
@Primary
@Bean
public Job simpleAsyncJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("simpleAsyncJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(new JobResultListener())
            .flow(simpleStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}

//Step config
@Bean
public Step simpleStep() {
    return steps.get("simpleStep")
            .<Type1, Type2>chunk(100)
            .reader(simpleReader(null))
            .processor(simpleProcessor())
            .writer(simpleDbWriter())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing entire lines in the execution context is not appropriate. However, storing a list of IDs is completely fine (even thousands of IDs).

Depending on what type of aggregation you are planning to do, the listener approach might work, but a separate step that does the aggregation is more appropriate IMO.

Comment: If there are multiple steps, then what could be the reader for the second step? Is passing data between steps with ExecutionContext a clunky use of Spring Batch?

Comment: The aggregation step does not need to be chunk-oriented, it could be a simple tasklet. Passing data between steps is a common requirement, and using the execution context for that is typical.